# Sleep method on child Thread causing Main Thread to sleep as well

Tags: java, multithreading

I created a very simple thread logic to see race condition but I saw an unexpected behavior and it makes me think I am missing some very important concept about Multithreading in Java.

Here's my Thread Class

```
public class MyThreadDoinNothing implements Runnable {
    private int count = 0;

    @Override public void run() {
        count++;
        System.out.println(count);
    }
}
```

And here is the MAIN

```
public class MAIN {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Thread[] threads=new Thread[100];
        Runnable object=new MyThreadDoinNothing();
        for (int i=0;i<100;i++) {
            threads[i] = new Thread(object);
            threads[i].start();
            threads[i].sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

I expected MAIN thread to run for ~1s and print 100 numbers with race condition.But what is happening that its taking 100 second whole program.I though threads[i].sleep(1000) should have made only that particular thread to sleep not the MAIN.

Not sure what I am missing here.

Answer (score 2):

The [`Thread.sleep(long)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep-long-) javadoc says (emphasis added)

> Causes the ***currently* executing** thread to sleep

The method is `static`, so you cannot invoke it on a specific `Thread` instance. Each of these calls,

```
threads[i].sleep(1000);
```

is *actually* doing

```
Thread.sleep(1000);
```

which is one reason why you should not invoke `static` methods through instances (and your compiler should be giving you a warning).

Comment: That explains very well.Thanks!

Comment: @leo017: note that David was first with a similar explanation

Answer (score 1):

You can't make another thread sleep. If a thread wants to sleep, it has to put itself to sleep.

You write each thread's code. So there should never be any reason to try to "reach into" another thread and make it do something. If a thread should sleep, it should be coded to sleep. If a thread isn't doing what you want it to do, fix it so it does.